# why xinetd can't run shell service

Tags: shell, format, xinetd

guys,i have a problem on using xinetd,the error message is 'xinetd[20126]: execv( /home/fulu/download/mysqlchk_status2.sh ) failed: Exec format error (errno = 8)'

1. the system operation is : CentOS release 6.2;
2. i installed the xinetd by the command 'sudo yum install xinetd'
3. i edited the /etc/services, add my port 6033 for my service named 'mysqlchk'
4. the service 'mysqlchk' in /etc/xinetd.d/mysqlchk is

   service mysqlchk
   {
           disable = no
           flags           = REUSE
           socket_type     = stream
           port            = 6033
           wait            = no
           user            = fulu
           server          = /home/fulu/download/mysqlchk_status2.sh
           log_on_failure  += USERID 
   }
5. the shell file /home/fulu/download/mysqlchk_status2.sh content is

   echo 'test'

6.i can run the command /home/fulu/download/mysqlchk_status2.sh straightly and get the result 'test'

1. when i telnet 127.0.0.1 6033,i get the output

   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to 127.0.0.1.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   Connection closed by foreign host.

then i tail the log file /var/log/messages,it shows

```
Apr 22 22:01:47 AY1304111122016 xinetd[20001]: START: mysqlchk pid=20126 from=127.0.0.1
Apr 22 22:01:47 AY1304111122016 xinetd[20126]: execv( /home/fulu/download/mysqlchk_status2.sh ) failed: Exec format error (errno = 8)
Apr 22 22:01:47 AY1304111122016 xinetd[20001]: EXIT: mysqlchk status=0 pid=20126 duration=0(sec)
```

i don't know why,can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, after questioning it i suddenly found the answer.  If you want the shell to be run in other program you need add '#!/bin/echo' at the first line of the shell file (of course the echo can be changed)